# How to fix “invalid access to memory location” error? - windbg

Tags: windbg

I am new to using windbg, and I am trying to set a breakpoint inside of the main function of a .net assembly that I am trying to debug, but am getting:

`` Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 000001d1`4465384e, Win32 error 0n998 "Invalid access to memory location." ``

I have tried using bp and bu $exentry to set a break point for the entry to the program, but even that is giving me the same error. I've tried searching other old stackoverflow topics on this issue and through google, but still haven't found a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd better learn native/managed debugging with windbg from a book or a course, instead of wasting a lot of time on shattered posts across the internet. For beginner/intermediate .NET developers, IMHO it is more important to learn how to use the managed debugger provided by VS, than windbg.

Comment: I have the same problem and VS simply does not work for me as it crashes and disappears from the screen too often. Looking for an alternative, I tried with WinDbgX and ended up with the same problem. @LexLi any recommendations for a book or a course (not for VS, but for WinDbg or some other alternative to VS for debugging managed apps)?

Comment: @xorcus You can find quite a lot useful posts from Tess https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/ There are several good dump analysis books which you can find on Amazon and LeanHub.

Answer (score 3):

Given a trivial .NET Console application compiled for .NET framework 4.7

```
using System;

namespace DebugNetMainMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("If you can read this, it's too late. You wanted to set a breakpoint earlier.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

you can use [WinDbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) to debug it.

1. Run WinDbg Preview
2. Choose "Launch Executable" and select the EXE
3. WinDbg will stop at the initial breakpoint

   ```
    ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
    7743ecc2 cc              int     3
   ```
4. At this point, you get the problem you described:

   ```
    0:000> bp $exentry
    0:000> bl
         0 e Disable Clear  007a27c6     0001 (0001)  0:**** DebugNetMainMethod!COM+_Entry_Point <PERF> (DebugNetMainMethod+0x27c6)
    0:000> g
    Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 007a27c6, Win32 error 0n998
        "Invalid access to memory location."
    0:000> bc 0
    0:000> bl
   ```

*Note:* In the future you want to provide exactly the information above, so everyone can reproduce your issue.

---

WinDbg is not made for .NET but for debugging "native code", i.e. code that was compiled for a specific processor like x86 or AMD64. WinDbg does not work well for Java, Python or .NET. However, for .NET, Microsoft provides an extension called SOS. You would typically load it like this:

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
Unable to find module 'clr'
```

But at this early stage of debugging, not many DLLs have been loaded and the `clr` is still missing. So let's postpone this:

```
0:000> sxe ld clrjit
0:000> g
[...]
ModLoad: 72950000 729da000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
[...]
0:000> .loadby sos clr
```

No output means it worked.

```
0:000> !bpmd DebugNetMainMethod Program.Main
Found 1 methods in module 00914044...
MethodDesc = 00914d5c
Adding pending breakpoints...

0:000> g
[...]
(2658.2e08): CLR notification exception - code e0444143 (first chance)
JITTED DebugNetMainMethod!DebugNetMainMethod.Program.Main()
Setting breakpoint: bp 00BA085F [DebugNetMainMethod.Program.Main()]
Breakpoint 2 hit

0:000> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x2e08 (0)
Child SP       IP Call Site
0075eff4 00ba085f DebugNetMainMethod.Program.Main() [C:\...\Program.cs @ 8]
0075f170 63dff036 [GCFrame: 0075f170] 

0:000> !u eip
Normal JIT generated code
DebugNetMainMethod.Program.Main()
Begin 00ba0848, size 32
[...]
```